# Delegate keyboard events from popup to opener in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I delegate keyboard events from a popup to its opener, please?

(I would like to enable application shortcuts even in its popup.)

The following does not work:

```
$(document).on('keydown keypress keyup', function (event) {
  $(opener.document).trigger(event);
});
```

Comment: Try registering to events from opener, like
window.open(...).on('keypress keydown keyup',function() {
//got events from popup
})

Comment: This has probably no relevance: I use [Mousetrap](http://craig.is/killing/mice) to handle shortcuts in the application.

Comment: You can modify Mousetraps sources, so it takes your popup during init, but not current window.

Check https://github.com/ccampbell/mousetrap/blob/master/mousetrap.js

Comment: It seems the problem is not in the delegation into a different window,* but in firing it as a keyboard event there. The following prints the event:

    `$(document).on('keydown keypress keyup', function (event) {`
      `console.log(event);`
    `});`

* Unless there is a security restriction which is not reported by my browsers.